# gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz in modern OpenGL

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I'm a beginner. I noticed in old code

```
// Calculate the light position for this vertex
vec3 vertex_light_position = gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz;
```

I assume that's dynamically changing and hence can't test it with simply a static vec3.

How do I go with replacing the above in modern OpenGL? An example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gl_LightSource is just an uniform array, for modern code you can just pass a uniform array of structures that contains your light data.

Answer (score 0):

It's more than likely static.  This code is grabbing the position *of* the light, not the vector *to* the light from the vertex.

It's also static with respect to the current rendering pass.  The vertex is at one location for the duration of the frame.

To retrieve information about lights in modern OpenGL, here is the [documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetLight.xml).

Comment: Hmm.  My professor in my computer graphics class literally just mentioned this yesterday.  And the documentation didn't mention it was deprecated (at least not on the page I linked to).  I wish they'd make it more obvious...

Comment: It is deprecated in latest spec. It is static though, thanks for the answer.